# How to use run keyword if on robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm writing a code on robot framework it is about comparing data between an excel file and mysql database. In my code, I can compare the datas successfully but also if there is mismatching I want to know in which column in. If I need to explain in more details, I have 66 columns and I know their names because it is written in excel document, let us think there are 2 mismatchings between excel and database, the code that I wrote gives me the wrong values like

```
1) Lists are different:
Index 0: 905390000510 != 905390000511 
2) Lists are different:
Index 0: 88975322100222 != 88975322100332
```

But every time it is written Index 0 so that I don't know where is the error. So I need to add if clause to my code in anywhere but I didn't achieve it yet because when I want to use `RUN KEYWORD` IF statement I get all column names but I need to get only that 2. How can I solve it? I add my code below.

```
*** Test Cases ***
open first excel file

    connect to database  pymysql  testdb  root  rootpass  localhost  3306
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    2  67
    \   open excel document  ${path1}  ${i}
    \   ${cname}  read excel cell  1  ${i}  Sheet2
    \   ${value1}=  read excel cell  2  ${i}  Sheet2
    \   @{list1}  create list  ${value1}
    \   @{queryResults}=  query  select a_${i} from test_table where a_1 = 'filename1'
    \   run keyword and continue on failure  lists should be equal  ${list1}  @{queryResults}
    \   run keyword if  "${list1}" !=" ${queryResults}"  log to console  ${cname}
```

And my excel file contains column names in first row, in second row there are datas.

Answer (score 2):

Although your script contains a list comparison, when looking a little closer it seems to me that this is not a list comparison, but a value comparison which should result in a message like

> In Row "1" Column "BBBB" value 2222 != 4444.

Below is an example where the values of two lists are compared and the column name is retrieved from the third when an error message is generated:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Compare List
    ${ListColumns}    Create List    AAAA    BBBB    CCCC     
    ${ListA}          Create List    1111    2222    3333
    ${ListB}          Create List    1111    4444    3333

    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    2
        run keyword and continue on failure  
        ...       should be equal as Strings      
        ...            @{ListA}[${i}]      
        ...            @{ListB}[${i}]
        ...            values=False
        ...            msg=In Row "${1}" Column "${ListColumns}[${i}]" value @{ListA}[${i}] != @{ListB}[${i}].
    END
```

This script will result in this console output:

```
==============================================================================
Compare List                                                          | FAIL |
In Row "1" Column "BBBB" value 2222 != 4444.
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SO004.Compare                                                         | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
SO004                                                                 | FAIL |
1 critical test, 0 passed, 1 failed
1 test total, 0 passed, 1 failed
==============================================================================
```

With this in mind you can apply this to your script in this manner. Keep in mind the below code is untested but should work.

```
Open First Excel File

    Connect To Database  pymysql  testdb  root  rootpass  localhost  3306

    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    2    67
        # Get the value and column
        open excel document  ${path1}  ${i}
        ${ColumnName}      read excel cell  1  ${i}  Sheet2
        ${Excelvalue}      read excel cell  2  ${i}  Sheet2   

        # This is a nested list where the @{queryResults}[0][0] means the first column from the first row.
        @{queryResults}    query  select a_${i} from test_table where a_1 = 'filename1'

        run keyword and continue on failure  
        ...       should be equal as Strings      
        ...            @{ListA}[${i}]      
        ...            @{ListB}[${i}]
        ...            values=False
        ...            msg=In Row "${1}" Column " ${ColumnName}" value ${Excelvalue} != @{queryResults}[0][0].
    END
```